# Adjust pane position in solid gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have adjust the width of solid gauge and the pane in the gauge has messed up. 
[image]

In highcharts jsfiddle itself, its coming like this only. Is there any workaround for this problem? Guys, help with this issue. I got stuck here for couple of hours and i cant solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour is specifying the size as 140% in pane property. As highcharts uses it for bugtracker. If you specify the size as 100%, it will work properly.

The jsfiddle link is attached with the comment below.